Give a message 10 minutes before restarting computer
I have this following script so I can force the download and installations of Windows updates.
I'm improving it so that after the installations of updates it gives me a pop-up message saying in 24h the computer will restart and 10 minutes before restarting gives another message saying the computer will restart in 10 min.
The question is I can't do the script to give the 10 min message before restarting.
Can you help me with this issue please?
This is a part of my script just to show the notifications.

function Show-BalloonTip {
    param (
        [string]$Title,
        [string]$Message
    )
    
    $notification = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
    $notification.Popup($Message, 10, $Title, 0x1)
}

function Schedule-Tasks {
    # Define o atraso para 24 horas e o aviso para 23 horas e 50 minutos
    $RebootDelayMinutes = 24 * 60
    $WarningDelayMinutes = $RebootDelayMinutes - 10

    # Calcula os horários de início com base nos atrasos
    $rebootTime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes($RebootDelayMinutes).ToString("HH:mm")
    $warningTime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes($WarningDelayMinutes).ToString("HH:mm")

    # Cria a tarefa agendada para o reinício
    schtasks /create /tn "ScheduledReboot" /tr "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command `"shutdown /r /f`"" /sc once /st $rebootTime /ru SYSTEM /f

    # Cria um script temporário para a mensagem de aviso
    $scriptPath = "C:\ProgramData\RebootWarning.ps1"
    $scriptContent = @"
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('The system will reboot in 10 minutes.', 'Reboot Warning')
"@
    Set-Content -Path $scriptPath -Value $scriptContent

    # Cria a tarefa agendada para a mensagem de aviso
    $escapedScriptPath = $scriptPath -replace ' ', '` '
    schtasks /create /tn "RebootWarning" /tr "powershell.exe -File `"$escapedScriptPath`"" /sc once /st $warningTime /ru SYSTEM /f
}




if (!$ListOnly -and !$NoAutoReboot) {
    Schedule-Tasks
    Show-BalloonTip -Title "Windows Updates" -Message "Updates installed. The system will reboot in 30 minutes. A warning will be displayed 10 minutes before the reboot."
}

I've tried everything i remember to do.
Bu my knowledge it's a little bit limited.

The only issue I see is what you expect to happen if the user Logged-out of his account prior to the reset? Due to reset time being calculated at runtime and saved in execution memory, logging out will kill the process without saving the reset time. Logging in will basically reset the timer. I think you should calculate the expected reset datetime, save it locally (file or registry) and empty it just before the reset. Rread from it upon execution.

@EliorMachlev: The core issue is use of the SYSTEM account, which by design cannot interact with the logged-on user's desktop. The scheduled execution time passed to schtasks.exe is statically persisted in the task scheduler database, so there's no concern about the scheduling user logging off and back on.


If you want to show a message to whatever user happens to be logged on when the scheduled task runs:

You must run with elevation (i.e. run from a session with elevated privileges, which requires running as administrator)

Replace /ru SYSTEM with /ru Users and add /it.[1]

Running a task with the built-in SYSTEM account by design can not interact with the desktop of the logged on user.

By contrast, targeting the Users group will run the task on the desktop of whatever user is logged on at the scheduled time.




Note:

If you know that the same user that runs schtasks.exe will also be the one logged in when the scheduled task executes, you can simply omit the /ru argument, in which case the schtasks.exe need not be made from an elevated session.

Therefore (whatever-user-is-logged-on solution):
#requires -RunAsAdministrator

# ...

# Note the /ru Users and /it options.
schtasks /create /tn "RebootWarning" /tr "powershell.exe -File `"$escapedScriptPath`"" /sc once /st $warningTime /ru Users /it /f

See the Schtasks.exe docs for more information.

[1] /it (the option that enables the task to run interactively) is not strictly necessary in this case, as targeting a user group such as Users allows the task to only run when a member of that group is logged on, in which case it invariably runs visibly on that user's desktop.
